# Javascript Eval and Function constructor usage

Tags: javascript

I'm currently experimenting on self replicating code. Out of love for the language I'd like to write it in javascript.

I'm working on a program that writes a function's code which in turn writes its function own code and so on. Basically, the desired process is this:

1. I manually create A function which returns code (which includes some randomness) and a numeric value (proposed solution to a problem).
2. I call this function a number of times, evaluate the results of each of those returned functions, and continue the process until I have code that is sufficiently good for what I'm trying to do.

Now, I have always been told how [eval is evil](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx), how [never to use it](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) and so on. However for my specific use case it seems like the Function constructor or eval are exactly what I'm looking for.

**So, in short the question is:**

Are eval/Function constructor indeed the best tools to use in my case? If so, I figured I'd use the Function constructor to scope the code executed, but is there a way to truly limit it from accessing the global scope? Also, what are some good practices for eval usage in my case?

Comment: Note: I did not label it with genetic programming since the question is strictly regarding the language specific practices for using eval/Function ctor,

Comment: For doing what you describe, `eval()` and the `Function()` constructor are your only tools anyway. They're only evil when used needlessly or incorrectly.

Comment: What about a controlled environment? I know I can integrate javascript into another language and use it for scripting inside the language, Is there a way to scope a javascript VM inside a javascript VM in order to prevent scope breach? (I'm not using a browser)

Comment: Well you could use Rhino from Java, but that's sort-of a pain. If you're doing what amounts to a research project, I don't see why it's important to protect the global scope, and it's probably just not possible anyway.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Did you mean generic programming ? Or please explain what did you mean by 'genetic programming'

Comment: @EvaCohen sure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I just figured out something I could use:

If I run my javascript code using node.js I can use the [vm](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) module which allows me to execute javascript code safely in a new context, and without letting the executed code have any access to the local or global scopes.

> vm.runInNewContext compiles code, then runs it in sandbox and returns the result. 
>    Running code does not have access to local scope. The object sandbox will be used as
>    the global object for code. sandbox and filename are optional, filename is only used in
>    stack traces.

You can see a full example here: [vm.runInNewContext](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runinnewcontext_code_sandbox_filename)

This will allow me to eval code safely, and seems to be the safest way (I found) currently available. I think this is a much better solution than eval or calling the Function constructor.

Thank you everyone who helped.

Comment: Yes, that's much better than `eval` in case you do want it in a new context *and* use nodejs.

Comment: Thanks, if you have any other suggestions I would love to hear them. nodejs seems like a good choice for a javascript environment anyway.

Comment: Yes, it's pretty much the only good choice if you don't need a browser and don't want it inside a JVM (where Rhino might be the preferred choice)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I believe there is no way to prevent it from accessing the global scope.  Suppose for example that in a web browser i evaled some code like this :

```
(function(window) {
   eval(script);
)(null));
```

Any time the script tries to access window - it will get an error, since window is null.  However someone who knew what they were doing could always do this :

```
var global = (function() {
    return this;
}());
```

Since when you invoke a function in what Crockford calls the "function invocation style" then the this is always bound to the global variable.

Comment: You don't even *need* an explicit reference to the global scope to access global variables.